# How to make java website

Tags: java, php, servlets

I want to make HTML website of course using CSS etc. But instead of using php for dynamic functions I would like to use Java. I have heard that there are plenty of web frameworks as Spring etc.

The problem is always when I search for tutorial - How to make java web? It shows me results with - web application, applet, servlet, JSP. I can't find short simple answer explaining how to start with that and what is the right thing to start with.

Would you mind telling me what should I use to make what I want? Just some short answer explaining what is what for. I remind you: I want to do some dynamic stuff on web based on Java instead of PHP.
EDIT:
I know I have to use dedicated server with Tomcat probably I am just looking for way to start. Should I start with the framework or?

Comment: its like searching a short simple answer to "how a computer work"

Comment: JSP is what you want.

Comment: This is not right site to ask such question. Here you ask aout specific problems with your code.
But to answer your question. Writing sites in java is not as easy as you probably hoping for.

Comment: This previous question may answer yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621228/how-do-you-make-websites-with-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personaly only used [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html) tutorials to learn about java-web and I'm satisfied with them, it has good-explained tutorials but it mostly teaches you how to process html templates with java.

If you do not want to follow thymeleaf tutorials, you should search for JAVA EE or JSP tutorials on either google or youtube, both provide well explained video tutorials for beginners

For my webserver I used [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) which is easy to use and good with debugging. I recommand it

EDIT: A web application may have one or more jsps (java server pages). Servlets are requests from the browser to the jsp.

Comment: I think this is great answer could you just please add the small difference among servlet, web application and jsp? I would so much appreciate it and mark it as answer. Thank you!:)

Comment: They are entirely different things, Have you tried reading about them on wikipedia first? you will not understand just by asking people. There is plenty of documentation available to teach you.

Comment: I already know everything I wanted I know servlet is html embed into java and JSP is the opposite, etc. :)

Answer (score 1):

You must have VPS or Dedicated Server to use, because shared web hostings doesn't support languages like Java, C, C++, Node.JS and so on...

Comment: There's always the chance of a PasS

Comment: So tell me how. I want to use Node.JS and Java on my shared hosting :)

Comment: There are always standalone executables and I've heard of quite a few hosting companies offering JSP support.

Comment: @GWSMaster you should give an eye to OpenShift